# Final, non-canonical NaN double value changes during runtime

Tags: java, jvm-crash

I am writing Java code that interacts with R, where "NA" values are distinguished from NaN values. NA indicates that a value is "statistically missing", that is it could not collected or is otherwise not available.

```
class DoubleVector {
     public static final double NA = Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff0000000001954L);

     public static boolean isNA(double input) {
         return Double.doubleToRawLongBits(input) == Double.doubleToRawLongBits(NA);
     }

     /// ... 
}
```

The following unit test demonstrates the relationship between NaN and NA and runs fine on my windows laptop but "isNA(NA) #2" fails *sometimes* on my ubuntu workstation.

```
@Test
public void test() {

    assertFalse("isNA(NaN) #1", DoubleVector.isNA(DoubleVector.NaN));
    assertTrue("isNaN(NaN)", Double.isNaN(DoubleVector.NaN));
    assertTrue("isNaN(NA)", Double.isNaN(DoubleVector.NA));
    assertTrue("isNA(NA) #2", DoubleVector.isNA(DoubleVector.NA));
    assertFalse("isNA(NaN)", DoubleVector.isNA(DoubleVector.NaN));
}
```

From debugging, it appears that DoubleVector.NA is changed to the canonical NaN value 7ff8000000000000L, but it's hard to tell because printing it to stdout gives different values than the debugger.

Also, the test only fails if it runs after a number of other previous tests; if I run this test alone, it always passes.

Is this a JVM bug? A side effect of optimization?

Tests always pass on:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Tests sometimes fail on:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are treading in very dangerous water here, one of the few areas where the Java VM behaviour is *not* exactly specified.

According to the JVM spec, there is only "a NaN value" in the `double` range. No arithmetic operation on doubles could distinguish between two different `NaN` values.

[The documentation of `longBitsToDouble()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29) has this note:

> Note that this method may not be able to return a `double` NaN with exactly same bit pattern as the long argument. IEEE 754 distinguishes between two kinds of NaNs, quiet NaNs and signaling NaNs. The differences between the two kinds of NaN are generally not visible in Java. Arithmetic operations on signaling NaNs turn them into quiet NaNs with a different, but often similar, bit pattern. However, on some processors merely copying a signaling NaN also performs that conversion. In particular, copying a signaling NaN to return it to the calling method may perform this conversion. So `longBitsToDouble` may not be able to return a double with a signaling NaN bit pattern. Consequently, for some long values, `doubleToRawLongBits(longBitsToDouble(start))` may not equal `start`. Moreover, which particular bit patterns represent signaling NaNs is platform dependent; although all NaN bit patterns, quiet or signaling, must be in the NaN range identified above.

So assuming that handling a `double` value will always keep the **specific** `NaN` value intact is a dangerous thing.

The **cleanest** solution would be to store your data in `long` and convert to `double` *after* checking for your special value. This will impose a quite noticeable performance impact, however.

You **might** get away by adding the `strictfp` flag at the affected places. This doesn't in any way *guarantee* that it will work, but it will (possibly) change how your JVM handles floating point values and *might* just be the necessary hint that helps. It will **still** not be portable, however.

Comment: Yikes that's worse than I imagined. But if this is a problem with inconsistencies between processors how could this work in R's C implementation?

Comment: Update: I have been able to avoid this issue by changing NA from a constant to a method that creates the double value on demand. I am guessing that something related to JIT compilation triggered the canonicalization of the constant. Still... I fear that Joachim is right in calling this dangerous.

Comment: @akbertram: Since C is usually not as well-defined as Java (i.e. it has a **lot** more "implementation-defined" and "undefined" behaviours), I'd be surprised if it were any better there. A language that has traditionally had **very strict** floating point handling is Fortran, there you could probably get away with that well within the definition of the language.

Comment: Update: Previously mentioned update didn't actually work :-( In further testing, it appears that the quiet/signaled bit cannot be relied upon, but the payload seems to be preserved. So 0x7ff8000000001954L works as "special" double value, though 0x7ff0000000001954L does not. http://bit.ly/jljLAU